# How to make an image that shows up fixed on the screen, but the visible area still scrolls away

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make an image that shows up fixed on the screen, but the visible area still scrolls away? Basically, it's like a window. The visible area of the image scrolls away with the page, but the whole image is fixed.

Comment: Hi, fixed means fixed to the viewport so it doesn’t scroll. Could you put up enough code and perhaps a diagram to show what you mean as it seems you are using the word fixed in a different way from CSS.

Comment: Can you please show us what did you try so far? Share your code! Also if you know the website which has this effect then can you share the link? I'm afraid that your question is wrongly asked or wrongly structured.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to describe it, and I don't have any code because I don't even know where to start

Answer (score 0):

I have too little reputations to write a comment so I have to write a reply.
Like @A Haworth wrote in the comments, you can give your image a class and use position: fixed in your CSS.
for example if you name the class img the css would look like this:

```
.img {
    position: fixed;
}
```

This link explains you how positions work in css: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp